# how to loop over an array and assign values to another component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have following component that i am working on

```
const propTypes = {
  items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    key: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    url: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
  ),
};

class Library extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selected: ‘papers’ };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <Dropdown
            options={[{ value: ‘test’, display: ’Test’ }]}
            name=“something”
            defaultValue=“test”
            required
          />
        </form>
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Library.propTypes = propTypes;

render(Library, 'library')
```

Dropdown component returns a dropdown of values. Props looks like

```
Props
0 {..}
  key: google
  url: www.google.com
1 {..}
  key: apple
  url: www.apple.com
```

Display maps to key and value maps to url so in dropdown i want to show keys from props. When clicked on it, Dropdown component returns the url.

How could i loop over the props and assign key to display and url to value?

Comment: can you post your `Dropdown` code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to pass your `items` object from prop to `Dropdown` component.

You can use map to iterate over your `items` prop and generate new array with the fields you need.

```
const propTypes = {
  items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    key: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    url: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
  ),
};

class Library extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selected: ‘papers’ };
  }

  render() {
    const newItems = this.props.items.map(item => {
        return {
            display: item.key,
            value: item.url,
        }
    })
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <Dropdown
            options={newItems}
            name=“something”
            defaultValue=“test”
            required
          />
        </form>
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Library.propTypes = propTypes;
```

If you are not familiar with `map` function, you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and watch [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCqtb-Z5YGQ) about it.

Comment: @magniticz i tried that but its display two separate dropdwons

Comment: @mike, try this one. if your Dropdown component acts as expected, it should display one dropdown with multiple (depending on how many items in props.items) options